# Getter for private member object in Java

Tags: java, oop

Say I have a class called `Truck` and one of the private member variables is of class `Wheel`. A getter for the `Wheel` variable, `getWheel`, would return a reference to it, as follows:

```
class Truck{
    private Wheel wheel;

    Truck(){
        wheel=new Wheel();

    }

    Wheel getWheel(){
        return this.wheel;
    }
}

class Wheel{
    int color;
}
```

Now, whoever calls `getWheel` will be able to modify the private member object at will:

```
class me{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Truck ye=new Truck();
        Wheel v=ye.getWheel();

        v.color=2;
    }
}
```

This would defeat encapsulation, wouldn't it?

What would be the right remedy for this?

Comment: Return a copy of `wheel`.

Comment: I don't think it defeats the encapsulation, you misunderstand the encapsulation, it doesn't mean the private object can't be modified, your code is the normal behavior we usually do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The usual approaches are:

- Make a defensive copy (e.g., return a *copy* of `Wheel`)
- Make `Wheel` immutable (any time you want to change it, you create a new one instead, constructed with the new color)
- Don't return `Wheel`, return an immutable interface on `Wheel` that only exposes getters, no mutation operations
- [As Sandeep said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43134784/157247), make the *setter* more restricted than the *getter*, say, package-private for the setter and `public` for the getter. Then classes within the package could set the color of `Wheel`, but classes outside the package cannot. (I prefer #3 in this situation for the clear separation, but this works too **if** you're crossing a visibility boundary.)

That third option is one of the reasons why making instance variables (fields) non-`private` is often considered poor practice.

Here's #3 in more depth, just because it's more complicated than #1 and #2, not because it's necessarily better (it isn't, design choices are made in context).

A read-only interface, typically public or package-private depending on how you're going to use all of this stuff:

```
public interface Wheel {
    int getColor();
}
```

The concrete class, typically package-private (could be a private static nested class within `Truck` if that's the only place it's used):

```
class WheelImplementation implements Wheel {
    private int color;

    WheelImplementation(int color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public int getColor() {
        return this.color;
    }

    void setColor(int color) {
        this.color = color;
    }
}
```

`Truck`, typically same visibility as `Wheel`:

```
public class Truck {
    private WheelImplementation wheel;

    Truck(){
        this.wheel = new WheelImplementation(/*...initial color...*/);
    }

    Wheel getWheel() {
        return this.wheel;
    }
}
```

Sure, that can be defeated through reflection, but generally you design an  API for use, rather than for abuse. :-)

Comment: Taking a step back...so by labeling `wheel` as a private member, all I did was make the pointer of the `wheel` object private. Whoever can get the address/pointer is able to modify the object, as I did above. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @FreshAir: Yes, technically. The only *complete* defence for that is #1 above: You don't give them the reference. But #2 and #3 are usually good enough: You give them the reference, but because of the type of the reference they have (`Wheel` instead of `WheelImplementation`, even though it points to a `WheelImplementation` object), they can't modify the instance unless they resort to reflection. When you're consuming an API, if you resort to reflection to modify the internals of what you receive, well, at that point you're abusing the API. :-)

Comment: Thanks Mr. Crowder for this detailed answer; I am still digesting the advanced approaches you mentioned. I noticed someone commented under my question, and he/she seems to imply the code in my question, without any remedies to the apparent issue, is how things are usually done in the industry - I'm a little surprised by this frankly. Would you agree with that comment?

Comment: @FreshAir: It completely depends on how `Truck` and `Wheel` are meant to be used. If it's important that the `Truck`'s `Wheel` isn't modified by code receiving it from `getWheel`, then no, that's not how it's usually done. If it doesn't matter whether that `Wheel` is modified by code getting it from `getWheel`, then yes, that's how it's normally done.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a private/package setter for wheel color.
Also, initialize the color in the constructor which would help you do that.

And like other answers, returning a copy of Wheel is also a good way to do this.

Comment: Good point, this can work in some situations where the API consumers you want to defend against are across a visibility boundary (like package-private vs. public).